# Reading random double from /dev/random (c)

Tags: c, linux, random

Still having trouble generating random seeds. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

double dev_random_seed(){
  double randval;
  FILE* f;

  f = fopen("/dev/random", "r");
  if(f == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: Failed to open /dev/random. Random seed defaults to 1. \n");
    return 1;
  }

  fread(&randval, sizeof(double), 1, f);
  fclose(f);
  return randval;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  double arse = dev_random_seed();

  printf("errno: %i\n",errno);
}
```

The output of which is:

```
errno: 22
```

which is EINVAL. Can't spot the mistake <strike>, I suck at c.</strike>

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, are you seeing the "WARNING" message or just the errno?

Comment: `errno` should only be queried in event of some failure. I can't see how `main()` can know to check `errno`?

Comment: it's a minimal working example to show that the code sets errno to 22 for some unknown reason

Comment: maybe it isn't actually not working... pretty hard to tell.

Comment: @Lucas, check return value of `fread()`, it should be `1`. Print the value of `errno` immediately after a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check errno unless you have an error.
It may be that a library sets a value of errno in advance because it represents a cause that a later part won't know IF the later part has an error (sorry that could be clearer)

See https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6619179

Comment: It seems that is what's happening. Though it is _not_ what some manuals says (but `man 3 fread` makes no claim either way).

Comment: @lucas sometimes in lib code you see setting errno to eg. "out of memory", then try an alloc, so if it fails you can exit out with the errno correctly set, if it succeeds it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yeah, I see why it's done. It makes sense. It's just that I saw something like "if there is an error, fread sets errno to 22" written a number of times in various places, which, I see now, is quite misleading.

Comment: @Lucas - the good thing is that once you've been bitten by it - you won't forget it ;-)

Comment: This answer is really misleading. Library functions are not supposed to set `errno` arbitrarily, if they do this is a bug. The advice to the OP should be to check all his system calls for error and act accordingly, as the comment of @hmjd indicates.

Comment: @JensGustedt whether it's a bug or not it's not uncommon. Sitting there complaining that it's a bug on a major OS or library doesn't get you paid.

Comment: @MartinBeckett, sure. But here it obviously is not a bug but a lack of checking the return values of system functions. Perhaps first one should look if the tools one uses are used corectly? And then complain?

Answer (score 0):

You should not check for errno if there were no error. To notify main that an error has occured, you may use the following code:

```
if (fread (&randval, sizeof(double), 1, f)<0) return NAN;
```

and, correspondingly, in main:

```
if (isnan (arse)) printf ("Error has occured: %i\n",errno);
```